# How can I show the compile progress in maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, compilation

Is it possible to configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` to show the compile progress? For example show for each source file when the compilation has completed.

At the moment I have a build container that outputs the following message:

```
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to /build/target/classes
```

Currently it hangs there since about 10 minutes and I am not sure what its doing. On my development machine it takes 6 seconds to run the compile target. I suspect the build has not enough memory and is taking too much time.

Comment: You tried to run the build with `-X`?

Comment: Yet but its quite verbose. I was looking for something that applies only to the compile plugin.

Comment: I don't know something specific for the compile plugin, but I would start by analysing the output of the maven command  `mvn clean compile -X`.

Comment: You simply can't cause the compiling is done under the hood by javac which has not that kind option (not that I know; never heard about something like this) apart from that what is the intention to do so? What kind of issues you are trying to solve?